# C#: Is it possible to return an IOrderedEnumerable<T>?

Tags: c#, generics, ienumerable

Is it possible to return an `IOrderedEnumerable<T>` from a method without using the `OrderBy` or `OrderByDescending` methods on an `IEnumerable<T>`?

Im guessing perhaps not... but... maybe I am wrong?

---

Reason: Mostly curiosity. It just kind of hit me when making [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829174/is-there-an-easy-way-to-turn-an-int-into-an-array-of-ints-of-each-digit/829476#829476) on returning digits in a number. And my method would return the digits in ascending order, according to their weight in the given number. So I thought it could be nice if they came out ordered in a way that the framework would recognize as ordered as well. Of course we can argue that from a common number point of view they were not ordered. But yeah... if they should or shouldn't wasn't the point here. Just if it was possible or not.

I guess I am also kind of implying a question (or am now at least) on if an `IOrderedEnumerable<T>` is more than just an `IEnumerable<T>` with a different name. Does it contain anything more? i know it has the `ThenBy` and `ThenByDescending` methods, but do they use anything inside the `IOrderedEnumerable<T>`, or is it just that they don't make sense to use directly on an `IEnumerable<T>`?

Comment: And why do you need this type?

Comment: Do you want a sorted collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can implement `IOrderedEnumerable<T>` yourself if you want too... it's not *hugely* hard, depending on what you need to do. The easiest option is just to call `OrderBy`/`OrderByDescending` though :)

Why are you interested?