# C#: How to implement IOrderedEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, .net, interface, ienumerable

I want to implement some various algorithms for practice, just to see how bad I really am and to get better :p

Anyways, I thought I would try to use `IEnumerable<T>` and `IOrderedEnumerable<T>` and other .Net collection types just to be compatible (so that what I write can be used more easily later).

But I can't find a way to return an instance of `IOrderedEnumerable<T>` other than using the OrderBy and ThenBy extension methods. So I guess I have to create my own class that implements this interface. But the interface doesn't quite make sense to me to be honest. It might, but I'm not sure.

I created an empty class, added the interface and then got ReSharper to add empty implementations for me. It looks like this:

```
class MyOrderedEnumerable<T> : IOrderedEnumerable<T>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Performs a subsequent ordering on the elements of an <see cref="T:System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable`1"/> according to a key.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// An <see cref="T:System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable`1"/> whose elements are sorted according to a key.
    /// </returns>
    /// <param name="keySelector">The <see cref="T:System.Func`2"/> used to extract the key for each element.</param><param name="comparer">The <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.IComparer`1"/> used to compare keys for placement in the returned sequence.</param><param name="descending">true to sort the elements in descending order; false to sort the elements in ascending order.</param><typeparam name="TKey">The type of the key produced by <paramref name="keySelector"/>.</typeparam><filterpriority>2</filterpriority>
    public IOrderedEnumerable<T> CreateOrderedEnumerable<TKey>(Func<T, TKey> keySelector, IComparer<TKey> comparer, bool descending)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns an enumerator that iterates through the collection.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// A <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator`1"/> that can be used to iterate through the collection.
    /// </returns>
    /// <filterpriority>1</filterpriority>
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns an enumerator that iterates through a collection.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// An <see cref="T:System.Collections.IEnumerator"/> object that can be used to iterate through the collection.
    /// </returns>
    /// <filterpriority>2</filterpriority>
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

What I don't understand is the `CreateOrderedEnumerable` method. What exactly is it meant to do? Well, I guess it of course would create an ordered enumerable, but how? Is the sorting algorithm itself supposed to go in there? And what will it sort? There is no collection of items going in to that method, so where is it meant to get the collection to order? How would you use the class? Is it meant to be implemented as for example a private helper class inside something that needs to sort stuff?

Then instead of a `MyOrderedEnumerable<T> : IOrderedEnumerable<T>`, you might have a `QuickSorter<T> : IOrderedEnumerable<T>` that took a collection in its constructor and sorted it when that `CreateOrderedEnumerable` method was called... but what would then happen if someone called `GetEnumerator` and started to enumerate before that method had been called?

---

Haha, just discovered I had asked something similar a while ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829487/c-is-it-possible-to-return-an-iorderedenumerablet). But that was just about if it was possible to return one. So I guess this question is a response to the one answer I got there =)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have a [sample implementation](https://csharpindepth.com/Files/LinqIn60Minutes.zip) you could look at. It's not designed to be efficient by any means, but it should get you started.

Basically an `IOrderedEnumerable<T>` just needs to have an idea of its current ordering, so it can create a new one. Assuming you already have an `IComparer<T>` you build a new one by saying something like:

```
int Compare(T first, T second)
{
    if (baseComparer != null)
    {
        int baseResult = baseComparer.Compare(first, second);
        if (baseResult != 0)
        {
            return baseResult;
        }
    }
    TKey firstKey = keySelector(first);
    TKey secondKey = keySelector(second);

    return comparer.Compare(firstKey, secondKey);        
}
```

So basically you create a chain of comparers going from the "least significant" up to the "most significant". You also need to put the "descending" bit in there, but that's easy :)

In the sample linked above, the three different aspects are represented in three different classes already present in [MiscUtil](https://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/miscutil):

- `ReverseComparer`: reverses an existing `IComparer<T>`'s results
- `LinkedComparer`: creates one comparer from two, with one master and one slave
- `ProjectionComparer`: creates a comparer based on a projection from the original items to keys, delegating to another comparer to compare those keys.

Comparers are great for chaining together like this.

Comment: Sweet! Will check it out at once =)

Comment: So it would reorder itself based on the new comparer you give it? or? not sure if I understood that...

Comment: It wouldn't reorder itself - it would create a new sequence with the new order, based on the old order and the new comparison. It wouldn't use the old sequence itself except to get at the original unordered data. Look at the code for more details :)

Comment: By the way, don't feel bad for getting confused by it - I did too for quite a while. It takes a bit of time to get your head round.

Comment: Sounds good. Am looking at the stuff now, and learning a lot =) Your zip file should have a Practice version too, with all the tests and all usings etc. fixed so that all tests fails. Could then start to implement and make tests pass one by one :p

Comment: Also it seems to be missing ThenBy... although I can kind of imagine how it would be with the LinkedComparer... which is brilliant btw! How do you people come up with all this stuff?? :p

Comment: I thiiink I get the IOrderedEnumerable now... the sorting goes in the GetEnumerator method, and then that CreateOrderedEnumerable creates a new IOrderedEnumerable with the comparer it has and the new one linked. Which means it would be used for ThenBy. Did I get it right?

Comment: Yup, that all sounds right :) ThenBy is just a simple wrapper for CreateOrderedEnumerable.

Comment: There's a case you can cheat in. If the ordering is known to be total (every item is definitely "less than" the next, rather than "equal to" it, by the sorting criteria) then `CreateOrderedEnumerable()` can just return another copy of the same collection, because `ThenBy` can't affect the order.

Comment: @HereticMonkey: Thanks for the edit. That's shown up a bug in the C# in Depth site, which I'm now fixing :) Will roll back the edit when it's working...

Answer (score -1):

Presumably, your class will have some internal storage variable that implements `IEnumerable` (`List<T>` for example).  Implementation of this method is simple in such a case:

```
private List<T> data = new List<T>();

public IOrderedEnumerable<CalculationResult> CreateOrderedEnumerable<TKey>(Func<CalculationResult, TKey> keySelector, IComparer<TKey> comparer, bool descending)
{
  return descending ? 
      data.OrderByDescending(keySelector, comparer) 
    : data.OrderBy(keySelector, comparer);
}
```

Comment: This is wrong. CreateOrderedEnumerable is called by the "ThenBy" LINQ function and must preserve the already existing ordering. Using your snippet to implement CreateOrderedEnumerable will override the order, causing your implementation to break the interface semantics.