# Best way to get an ordered list of groups by value from an unordered list

Tags: c#, linq

I'd like to know if there's a more efficient way to get an ordered list of groups by value from an initially unordered list, than using `GroupBy()` followed by `OrderBy()`, like this:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> orderedGroups = list.GroupBy(x => x).OrderBy(x => x.Key);
```

For more detail, I have a large `List<T>` which I'd like to sort, however there are lots of duplicate values so I want to return the results as `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>`, much as `GroupBy()` returns an `IEnumerable` of groups. If I use `OrderBy()`, I just get `IEnumerable<T>`, with no easy way to know whether the value has changed from one item to the next. I could group the list then sort the groups, but the list is large so this ends up being slow. Since `OrderBy()` returns an `OrderedEnumerable` which can then be sorted on a secondary field using `ThenBy()`, it must internally distinguish between adjacent items with the same or different values.

Is there any way I can make use of the fact that `OrderedEnumerable<T>` must internally group its results by value (in order to facilitate `ThenBy()`), or otherwise what's the most efficient way to use LINQ to get an ordered list of groups?

Comment: Posting your code would help.

Comment: Added an example implementation which hopefully can be improved upon

Comment: Can you use .Distinct() ?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and the desired result?

Comment: Mairaj, Distinct() is really just a special case of GroupBy(), I'm not sure how it would help here

Comment: Delay incuring the sort penalty until you need it, just group it first, will not work?  have you try sort it first then group it and see if it is faster than grouping then sorting?  `OrderBy` and `ThenBy` will just basically create a field which concatenate the value in order of appearance and link it the actual object reference.  It won't sort it until you execute the query internally I think (at least that how I'd implement that). Sort happen on the temporary index and value get copied of using the reference into the right position in the new enumerable.

Comment: Ham3d, try plugging a list of a million or so random 5 digit ints into the sample code above

Comment: Jimmy, I think pulling the first value from the result necessarily incurs the penalty of the sort, since it must be the first member of the group with the smallest value.

Comment: try reorder your code. list.OrderBy(x => x.Key).GroupBy(x => x).ToDictionary(x=> x.Key, y=> y.ToList());

Comment: There is no built-in. You could roll your own.

Comment: I think your best option here is to use a `SortedDictioanry`

Comment: @JonG I'm just going to say... try timing it. Because I tried with a list of 1000000 random five-digit integers and `GroupBy(i => i).OrderBy(g => g.Key)` was 25% faster than just `OrderBy(i => i)`.

Comment: What you have is fine. A handrolled solution can be seen at https://ideone.com/HBWY02

Comment: @JonG: are you actually trying to do a GroupBy()? Because in your posted code, you're just grouping by the values in your collection, which is the same as `Distinct()`.

Comment: StriplingWarrior - it's not quite the same, GroupBy() returns IEnumerable of group of T, whereas Distinct() returns IEnumerable of T

Answer (score 3):

- You can use [ToLookup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549073%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), which returns an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>` and then do `OrderBy` for values of each key on demand. This will be O(n) to create the lookup and O(h) to order elements under each group (values for a key) assuming h is the number of elements under a group
- You can improve the performance to amortized O(n) by using `IDictionary<TKey, IOrderedEnumerable<T>>`. But if you want to order by multiple properties, it will again by O(h) on the group. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1234918/147613) for more info on IOrderedEnumerable. You can also use `SortedList<TKey, TValue>` instead of `IOrderedEnumerable`

[Update]:

Here is [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5013740/147613) which you can take a look. But again, it involves doing OrderBy on top of the result.

Further, you can come up with your own data structure as I don't see any data structure available on BCL meeting this requrement.

One possible implementation:

You can have a Binary Search Tree which does search/delete/insert in O(longN) on an average. And doing an in-order traversal will give you sorted keys. Each node on the tree will have an ordered collection for example, for the values.

node roughly looks like this:

```
public class MyNode
{
    prop string key;
    prop SortedCollection myCollection;
}
```

You can traverse over the initial collection once and create this special data structure which can be queried to get fast results.

[Update 2]:
if you have possible keys below 100k, then I feel implementing your own data structure is an overkill. Generally an order by will return pretty fast and the time taken is tiny. Unless you have large data and you do order by multiple times, ToLookup should work fairly well.

Comment: I really like ToLookup(), had never noticed that method before. However, in this case the benefit of key-based retrieval doesn't help with the need to sort the keys, so even if I replace GroupBy() with ToLookup(), I still have to sort the entire IEnumerable<IGrouping>> by the key.

Comment: there is no DataStructure available out of the box on BCL which can provide ordered keys and ordered values. if you use dictionary/group then order of keys are not guaranteed. you will have to do an order by on it. You can come up with your own DataStructure which stores ordered keys and ordered IList/IEnumerable as value value.

Comment: @Amit What makes you think he needs ordered values?

Comment: @Rawling, looks like you are right, I read the OrderedEnumerable<T> to be ordered values.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, you're not going to do much better than

```
items.GroupBy(i => i.KeyProperty).OrderBy(g => g.Key);
```

`GroupBy` is an `O(n)` operation. The `OrderBy` is then `O(k log k)` where `k` is the number of groups.

If you call `OrderBy` first... well, firstly, your `O(n log n)` is now in your number of items rather than your number of groups, so it's already slower than the above.

And secondly, an `IOrderedEnumerable` *doesn't have the internal magic you think it does*. It isn't an ordered sequence that contains groups of same-ordered items which can then by reordered with `ThenBy`; it's an unordered sequence with a list of sort keys which `ThenBy` *adds to*, which is eventually ordered by each of those keys when you iterate over it.

You may be able to eke out a little more speed by rolling your own "group and sort" loop, maybe manually adding to an `SortedDictionary<TKey, IList<TItem>>`, but I don't think you're going to get a better big O than what out-of-the-box LINQ gets you.LINQ

Comment: I remember reading somewhere that OrderedDictionary is indexed based on insertion order and the name should have been IndexedDixtionary. Just something to be aware about the class.

Comment: @Amit Whoops. I meant `SortedDictionary`. Cheers for making me look it up!

Comment: Having reflected on the classes involved, I can see you're right about OrderedEnumerable, the sort is performed using quicksort which doesn't explicitly group items of the same value

Answer (score 0):

I think iterating thru the list `for(;;)` as you populate `Dictionary<T, int>`, where value is count of repeated elements will be faster.