# Deserialization of IOrderedEnumerable<T> with JSON.NET

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, json-deserialization

My team and I came accross a weird behavior with JSON.NET deserialization in C#.

We have a simple ViewModel with a `IOrderedEnumerable<long>` :

```
public class TestClass
{
    public IOrderedEnumerable<long> orderedDatas { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public TestClass(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.orderedDatas = new List<long>().OrderBy(p => p);
    }
}
```

Then, we just want to POST/PUT this viewmodel in an API controller

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]TestClass test)
{
    return Ok(test);
}
```

Calling this API with a json that look like that :

```
{
    Name: "tiit",
    "orderedDatas": [
        2,
        3,
        4
    ],
}
```

**With this call, we saw that the constructor wasn't called (which can be explained by the fact that it's not a default constructor). But the strange thing is that if we change the type of the collection to `IEnumerable` or `IList`, the constructor is properly called.**

If we change the constructor of `TestClass` to be a default one :

```
public class TestClass
{
    public IOrderedEnumerable<long> orderedDatas { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public TestClass()
    {
        this.Name = "default";
        this.orderedDatas = new List<long>().OrderBy(i => i);
    }
}
```

The object retrieve by the controller will not be null.
And if we change the type of the collection to `IEnumerable` and we keep the constructor with a parameter (public `TestClass(string name)`), it'll work also.

Another strange thing is that the object test in the controller is "null". Not only the orderedDatas is null, but the entire object.

If we add an attribute `[JsonObject]` on the class, and an `[JsonIgnore]` on the property orderedData, it works.

For now, we changed the object to a simple List and it's working fine, but we were wondering why the JSON deserialization act different depending on the type of the collection.

If we use directly the JsonConvert.Deserialize :

```
var json = "{ Name: 'tiit', 'orderedDatas': [2,3,4,332232] }";
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestClass>(json);
```

we can saw the actual exception :

> Cannot create and populate list type
>   System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable`1[System.Int64]. Path 'orderedDatas',
>   line 1, position 33.

Any idea / help is appreciated.

Thanks !

** Edit : thanks for your answers. There is one thing that I keep finding weird (I put it in bold), if you have any idea to explain this behavior, please tell me **

Comment: `IOrderedEnumerable` is just an interface. Lists and arrays are *not* ordered, so they don't implement that interface. If you want a specific collection type to be used instead of arrays, you should probably use a custom converter that creates the type you want (SortedList perhaps?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As kisu states in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39373235/3744182), Json.NET fails to deserialize your `TestClass` because it has no built-in logic for mapping the `IOrderedEnumerable<T>` interface to a concrete class as is required to deserialize it.  This is not surprising, because:

1. [`IOrderedEnumerable<TElement>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534852(v=vs.110).aspx) has no publicly available property indicating how it is sorted -- ascending; descending; using some complex [`keySelector`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966(v=vs.110).aspx) delegate that refers to one or more [captured variables](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/matt/2008/03/01/understanding-variable-capturing-in-c/).  Thus this information would be lost during serialization - and serializing a delegate such as the `keySelector` delegate anyway isn't implemented even if the information were public.
2. The concrete .Net class that implements this interface, [`OrderedEnumerable<TElement, TKey>`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,2d89a8f513559ba0,references), is **`internal`**.  Normally it is returned by `Enumerable.OrderBy()` or `Enumerable.ThenBy()` not created directly in application code.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234901/c-how-to-implement-iorderedenumerablet) for a sample implementation.

A *minimal* change to your `TestClass` to make it serializable by Json.NET would be to add `params long [] orderedDatas` to your its constructor:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public IOrderedEnumerable<long> orderedDatas { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public TestClass(string name, params long [] orderedDatas)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.orderedDatas = orderedDatas.OrderBy(i => i);
    }
}
```

This takes advantage of the fact that, when a type has exactly one public constructor, if that constructor is parameterized, Json.NET will invoke it to construct instances of the type, *matching and deserializing JSON properties to constructor arguments by name (modulo case)*.

That being said, I don't recommend this design.  From the reference source for [`OrderedEnumerable<TElement, TKey>.GetEnumerator()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs.html,23c6be2fd074160a,references) we can see that the underlying enumerable is re-sorted *each time `GetEnumerator()` is called*.  Thus your implementation could be quite inefficient.  And of course the ordering logic will be lost after round-tripping.  To see what I mean, consider the following:

```
var test = new TestClass("tiit");
int factor = 1;
test.orderedDatas = new[] { 1L, 6L }.OrderBy(i => factor * i);
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test, Formatting.Indented));
factor = -1;
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test, Formatting.Indented));
```

The first call to `Console.WriteLine()` prints

```
{
  "orderedDatas": [
    1,
    6
  ],
  "Name": "tiit"
}
```

And the second prints

```
{
  "orderedDatas": [
    6,
    1
  ],
  "Name": "tiit"
}
```

As you can see, `orderedDatas` is re-sorted every time it is enumerated, according to the current value of the captured variable `factor`.  All that Json.NET could do is to *snapshot* the current sequence when serializing, it has no way to serialize the *dynamic logic* of how the sequence constantly re-sorts itself.

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KnCZjk).

Of course, when you change the property to be `IList<long>` then no exception is thrown and the object will be deserialized.  Json.NET has built-in logic to deserialize the interfaces `IList<T>` and `IEnumerable<T>` as `List<T>`.  It has no built-in concrete type to use for `IOrderedEnumerable<T>` for the reasons explained.

**Update**

You ask, to paraphrase, *why is the parameterized constructor not called when trying and failing to deserialize a nested `IOrderedEnumerable<T>` property, while the parameterless constructor is called?*

Json.NET uses a different order of operations when deserializing objects with and without a parameterized constructor.  That difference is explained in the answer to the question [Usage of non-default constructor breaks order of deserialization in Json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36866131/usage-of-non-default-constructor-breaks-order-of-deserialization-in-json-net/36871402#36871402).  Bearing that answer in mind, when exactly does Json.NET throw the exception from trying and failing to deserialize an instance of type `IOrderedEnumerable<T>`?

1. When the type has a parameterized constructor, Json.NET will chew through the properties in the JSON file and deserialize values for each one *before* constructing the object, then pass the appropriate values into the constructor.  Thus when the exception gets thrown the object is not constructed.
2. When the type has a parameterless constructor, Json.NET will construct an instance and begin to chew through the JSON properties to deserialize them, throwing the exception partway through.  Thus when the exception gets thrown the object is constructed but not fully deserialized.

Apparently, somewhere in your framework the exception from Json.NET is getting caught and swallowed.  So in case #1 you get a `null` object and in case #2 you get a partially deserialized object.

Answer (score 3):

From what I can see in constructor of `JsonArrayContract`, interface `IOrderedEnumerable<>` is not correctly handled, most likely because it is not implemented by `List<>` and `T[]` and therefore needs some more special treatment and basically can be replaced by some other interface.

Also, putting size-less interfaces inside a deserialized class does not make sense, because by definition, they cannot be infinite and can be replaced by collection that has finite, known size.

Remember that using interfaces in deserialized objects involves some "guess work" from the deserializer to create a correct instance.

If you want some immutable collection with specified order, I would advise you to go with `IReadOnlyList<>`.