# I need to check if each digit from an integer is even or odd in c# an return even or odd

Tags: c#

I'm new to c# language and still learning. I have to write a console application (like example) but the real problem for me is that I don't know how to access each number for the input integer and pass it on the division function (n %  2 ==0) and return even/odd for the given number.

For example:
the user input: 4444
and the console result: even
even
even
even

```
        string inputData = Console.ReadLine(); // the 4 digit number
        int number = Convert.ToInt32(inputData);
        string emptyStr = String.Empty;
        string divided = "even";
        string notDivided = "odd";
       // here .......????
        if (number % 2 == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(divided);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(notDivided);

        }
```

Comment: You can convert the integer to a string, loop over its characters and convert each char back to an int.

Comment: You can either use /10 and %10 to extract digits one by one, but that's usually easiest to do right-to-left not left-to-right, or you can use .ToString().

Comment: I think this will answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829174/is-there-an-easy-way-to-turn-an-int-into-an-array-of-ints-of-each-digit

Comment: " the user input: 4444" the user cannot input an `int` into a program. It will always be a string! In this case you can iterate with a loop over the string convert each character into an `int` (please don't forget to call `ToString()` on the character!!!) and feed it as n into your function

Comment: please post your entire code, we can then pint point directly your problems and help you to solve them

Comment: Please show what code you have so far (eg, where you get the user input) and I'm sure someone can show you how to turn each character typed to an integer.

Comment: Thank you all for your input :) I will try some of them in a short time. I put the code that I have

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for.

First of all use this
[Is there an easy way to turn an int into an array of ints of each digit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829174/is-there-an-easy-way-to-turn-an-int-into-an-array-of-ints-of-each-digit)

After that just check every individual item in your array

```
public void main
{

   var numbers = NumbersIn(987654321).ToArray();
   foreach (int element in numbers)
   {
      if (element % 2 == 0)
      {
         Console.Write("even");
      }
      else
      {
         Console.Write("uneven");
      }
   }
}
        

public Stack<int> NumbersIn(int value)
{
    if (value == 0) return new Stack<int>();

    var numbers = NumbersIn(value / 10);

    numbers.Push(value % 10);

    return numbers;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readline?view=netcore-3.1 you can use the hyperlink provided to use the method Console.ReadLine method for the conditional output that you are C#-ing.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to contribute, however it's advised not to post links as answers. In a couple of years somebody might stumble upon this question and the link might not work anymore. So quote the relevant parts from a link and add some context and story around it. Linking to extra information can be fine but an answer should be complete without reliance on external sources.

Comment: Thank you for your interest in my participation. I will try to focus more on what the right answer based more on code and lesser on hyperlinks examples.

Answer (score -1):

You can read each key written by user in loop with:

`var digit = Console.ReadKey()`

Remember to parse char to int properly.

As Mong Zhu noticed, you cannot parse char value with: `Int32.Parse('1')`. You have to do it with string value.

So full solution is:

```
var digitStr = Console.ReadKey();
var digit = Int32.Parse(digitStr.KeyChar.ToString());
```

Comment: @ Mong Zhu that is super strange why does this happen?

Comment: @JoeriE because converting the char `4` to an integer gives you its character code not its string representation.

Comment: Although in fairness if you're just testing for even or odd then the character codes will work fine.

Comment: @Rup ha yes by coincidence the character codes for odd number chars are also odd.