# How do I replace a digit in an Int32 without turning it into a string?

Tags: c#, .net, string, replace, integer

```
var digitToSubstitute = 5;

var targetNumber   = 999999999;
var expectedOutput = 995999999;
```

How do I replace the n-th digit in an int32 without converting it to/from a string?

While this is a small sample, in real-life application I use this in a tight loop (to create all possible number combinations and check against existing ones), so I'd like to avoid creating strings.

Comment: Is `digidToSubstitute` a random number below 10? Does `targetNumber` alsway consist out of 9 digits?

Comment: And `999999999` can be `382746589` at some point, when you want to change the seventh digid to 5?

Comment: Would you be ok converting your big number into an array of single digit numbers? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829174/is-there-an-easy-way-to-turn-an-int-into-an-array-of-ints-of-each-digit

Comment: @CS1061, ```digitToSubstitute``` is a number between 0 and 9 and the ```targetNumber```    always consists of 9 digits

Comment: rshepp beated me.

Comment: It seems like you are manipulating a string, not a number.  And the best way to avoid creating strings is to use `StringBuilder`, which you can overwrite in-place as many times as necessary, without creating new garbage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this. Not sure how this performs compared to string manipulation.

```
int ReplaceNthDigit(int value, int digitPosition, int digitToReplace, bool fromLeft = false)
{
    if (fromLeft) {
        digitPosition = 1 + (int)Math.Ceiling(Math.Log10(value)) - digitPosition;
    }

    int divisor = (int)Math.Pow(10, digitPosition - 1);
    int quotient = value / divisor;
    int remainder = value % divisor;
    int digitAtPosition = quotient % 10;
    return (quotient - digitAtPosition + digitToReplace) * divisor + remainder;
}

Console.WriteLine(ReplaceNthDigit(999999999, 7, 5, fromLeft: true)); // 999999599
Console.WriteLine(ReplaceNthDigit(999999999, 7, 5, fromLeft: false)); // 995999999
```

> Note: won't work for negative numbers.

Comment: you'd need to use modulus, rather than remainder, if you intended to support negative numbers.

Comment: Thanks! It it possible to make it count digits from the start of the number, not from the end though?

Comment: Sure, base 10 logarithms are useful for this. See edit